# Pandas : balancing data

Tags: python, pandas

**Note: This question is not the same as an answer here: "Pandas: sample each group after groupby"**

Trying to figure out how to use `pandas.DataFrame.sample` or any other function to balance this data:

```
df[class].value_counts()

c1    9170
c2    5266
c3    4523
c4    2193
c5    1956
c6    1896
c7    1580
c8    1407
c9    1324
```

I need to get a random sample of each class (c1, c2, .. c9) where sample size is equal to the size of a class with min number of instances. In this example sample size should be the size of class c9 = 1324.

Any simple way to do this with Pandas?

**Update**

To clarify my question, in the table above :

```
c1    9170
c2    5266
c3    4523
...
```

Numbers are counts of instances of c1,c2,c3,... classes, so actual data looks like this:

```
c1 'foo'
c2 'bar'
c1 'foo-2'
c1 'foo-145'
c1 'xxx-07'
c2 'zzz'
...
```

etc.

**Update 2**

To clarify more:

```
d = {'class':['c1','c2','c1','c1','c2','c1','c1','c2','c3','c3'],
     'val': [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,3]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    class   val
0   c1  1
1   c2  2
2   c1  1
3   c1  1
4   c2  2
5   c1  1
6   c1  1
7   c2  2
8   c3  3
9   c3  3

df['class'].value_counts()

c1    5
c2    3
c3    2
Name: class, dtype: int64

g = df.groupby('class')
g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()))

        class   val
class           
c1  6   c1  1
    5   c1  1
c2  4   c2  2  
    1   c2  2
c3  9   c3  3
    8   c3  3
```

Looks like this works. Main questions:

How `g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()))` works? I know what 'lambda` is, but:

- What is passed to `lambda` in `x` in this case?
- What is `g` in `g.size()`?
- Why output contains  6,5,4, 1,8,9 numbers? What do they
  mean?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
g = df.groupby('class')
g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()).reset_index(drop=True))

  class  val
0    c1    1
1    c1    1
2    c2    2
3    c2    2
4    c3    3
5    c3    3
```

---

**Answers to your follow-up questions**

1. The `x` in the `lambda` ends up being a dataframe that is the subset of `df` represented by the group.  Each of these dataframes, one for each group, gets passed through this `lambda`.
2. `g` is the `groupby` object.  I placed it in a named variable because I planned on using it twice.  `df.groupby('class').size()` is an alternative way to do `df['class'].value_counts()` but since I was going to `groupby` anyway, I might as well reuse the same `groupby`, use a `size` to get the value counts... saves time.
3. Those numbers are the the index values from `df` that go with the sampling.  I added `reset_index(drop=True)` to get rid of it.

Comment: Should `reset_index` go _outside_ the lambda for the posted result (i.e. `apply(...).reset_index(...)`? I get a `MultiIndex` with the code as posted.

Answer (score 17):

The above answer is correct but I would love to specify that the **g** above is not a **`Pandas DataFrame`** object which the user most likely wants. It is a **`pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`** object. Pandas apply does not modify the dataframe inplace but returns a dataframe. To see this, try calling `head` on **g** and the result will be as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'class':['c1','c2','c1','c1','c2','c1','c1','c2','c3','c3'],
     'val': [1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,3,3]
    }

d = pd.DataFrame(d)
g = d.groupby('class')
g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()).reset_index(drop=True))
g.head()
>>> class val
0    c1    1
1    c2    2
2    c1    1
3    c1    1
4    c2    2
5    c1    1
6    c1    1
7    c2    2
8    c3    3
9    c3    3
```

To fix this, you can either create a new variable `or` assign **g** to the result of the **apply** as shown below so that you get a `Pandas DataFrame`:

```
g = d.groupby('class')
g = pd.DataFrame(g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()).reset_index(drop=True)))
```

Calling the head now yields:

```
g.head()

>>>class val
0   c1   1
1   c2   2
2   c1   1
3   c1   1
4   c2   2
```

Which is most likely what the user wants.

Comment: The result of `g.apply` is a `DataFrame`, no need for this conversion. Check for yourself: `type(g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(g.size().min()).reset_index(drop=True)))`. The reason you see this behavior in your example is because `apply` does not modify the object in place -- it _returns_ a `DataFrame`.

Comment: This is wrong, as @ntjess pointed out, there is no need for the conversion. Don't spread misinformation. It's worrying that this answer was upvoted.  The result of  `g.apply(...)` and `g`  are two different objects. The first is a `DataFrame` which results from aggregating the `DataFrameGroupBy` object that `g` refers to.

Comment: This also has the potential to be unnecessarily computationally complex if the number of classes is large. It is advisable to store the min and reuse that value during sampling, i.e. `min_num_samps = g.size().min(); d = g.apply(lambda x: x.sample(min_num_samps).reset_index(drop=True))`

Answer (score 13):

This method get randomly k elements of each class.

```
def sampling_k_elements(group, k=3):
    if len(group) < k:
        return group
    return group.sample(k)

balanced = df.groupby('class').apply(sampling_k_elements).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: An explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

"The following code works for undersampling of unbalanced classes but it's too much sorry for that.Try it! And also it works the same for upsampling problems! Good Luck!"

## Import required sampling libraries

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
```

## Define the majority and minority class

```
 df_minority9 = df[df['class']=='c9']
    df_majority1 = df[df['class']=='c1']
    df_majority2 = df[df['class']=='c2']
    df_majority3 = df[df['class']=='c3']
    df_majority4 = df[df['class']=='c4']
    df_majority5 = df[df['class']=='c5']
    df_majority6 = df[df['class']=='c6']
    df_majority7 = df[df['class']=='c7']
    df_majority8 = df[df['class']=='c8']
```

## Unndersample majority class

```
 maj_class1 = resample(df_majority1, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class2 = resample(df_majority2, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class3 = resample(df_majority3, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class4 = resample(df_majority4, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class5 = resample(df_majority5, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class6 = resample(df_majority6, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class7 = resample(df_majority7, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123) 
    maj_class8 = resample(df_majority8, 
                                 replace=True,     
                                 n_samples=1324,    
                                 random_state=123)
```

## Combine minority class with undersampled majority class

```
df=pd.concat([df_minority9,maj_class1,maj_class2,maj_class3,maj_class4, maj_class5,dmaj_class6,maj_class7,maj_class8])
```

## Display new balanced class counts

```
 df['class'].value_counts()
```

Comment: This can be automated by a for loop or a lambda function.

Comment: This answer is so badly written. I am tempted to downvote. But then, if I downvote, I will lose a point. But, this is really poorly written (especially given the fact that someone has already commented about using a loop)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I stumbled across it and wasn't really happy with the solutions here and in other threads. I made a quick solution using list comprehension that works for me. Maybe it is useful to someone else:

```
df_for_training_grouped = df_for_training.groupby("sentiment")
df_for_training_grouped.groups.values()
frames_of_groups = [x.sample(df_for_training_grouped.size().min()) for y, x in df_for_training_grouped]
new_df = pd.concat(frames_of_groups)
```

The result is a dataframe which contains the same amount of entries for each group. The amount of entries is set to the size of the smallest group.

Comment: This solution saves the 'Index' column.