# Drop Pandas rows to have even distribution of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a Pandas DF with a column "label". Let's say there are five rows in the DF and the values of labels are as follows [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]. Is there a built-in function in Pandas so I can remove one row with label 1 so the values are evenly distributed (count of 0's and 1's is the same)?

Comment: What do you mean by evenly distributed? That they have the same amount of 1 and zeros?

Comment: I edited the original so it should be more clear.

Comment: So if you 10 1s and 2 0s you want a Dataframe with 2 1s and 2 0s?

Comment: Does this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839316/pandas-balancing-data

Comment: That would have equal count of 1s and 0s, so no rows would need to be removed. If there was 16 1s and 10 0s, I would like to remove 6x 1s. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: I believe it does, thanks for the help.