# keep a certain number of rows from a specific group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns. I want to order by city and keep, for 'city' == 'Buenos Aires', a certain number of rows. And for 'city' == 'Paris', another number of rows. Which is the best way to do it? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839316/pandas-balancing-data) is shown a way to keep the same number of rows for each group. But I want a different number of rows.

```
    city            number
0   Buenos Aires    14
1   Paris           23
2   Barcelona       12
3   Buenos Aires    14
4   Buenos Aires    14
... ...             ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas get topmost n records within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009/pandas-get-topmost-n-records-within-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a dictionary of the number of values to keep:

```
d = {'Buenos Aires': 2, 'Paris': 3}

out = df.groupby('city').apply(lambda g: g.head(d.get(g.name, 0)))
```

*NB. for random rows, use `sample` in place of `head`.*

Alternative with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
d = {'Buenos Aires': 2, 'Paris': 3}

out = (df[df['city'].map(d).lt(df.groupby('city').cumcount())]
       .sort_values(by='city')
      )
```